# upload XML -> read unicode stream and convert it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, encoding

I have a fileupload control where i can upload xml documents.

The XML files will be encoded in unicode format. I want to convert them to UTF8, so they can render as a proper xml file.

Im saving the uploaded file in a hiddenfield as a hex string and sends it to a generic handler. What i want is a result that i can create an xml from. At the moment my string looks like this:

```
"??<\0?\0x\0m\0l\0 \0v\0e\0r\0s\0i\0o\0n\0=\0\"\01\0.\00\0\"\0 \0e\0n\0c\0o\0d\0i\0n\0g\0=\0\"\0I\0S\0O\0-
```

Instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0".. etc
```

Code:

```
if (fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/xml")
{
      Stream inputstream = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;

      byte[] streamAsBytes = (ConvertStreamToByteArray(inputstream));

      string stringToSend = BitConverter.ToString(streamAsBytes);

      xmlstream.Value = stringToSend;

      sendXML.Visible = true;
      infoLabel.Text = "<b>Selected XML: </b>" + fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
}
```

handler.ashx:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["xmldata"] != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            string xmlstring = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["xmldata"];

            byte[] data = xmlstring.Split('-').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray();

            string complete = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(complete);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc.InnerXml);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not at all clear that you really *should* do this. XML files can declare their own encoding, and it looks like yours is declaring an encoding starting with "ISO" (that's where the data you've given us stops). That's probably *not* UTF-8.

Basically, I don't think you should be treating the data as text in handler.ashx. Just get `XmlDocument` to parse it from a stream. It's not really clear *exactly* how your upload code is sending the data, but you should try to mess with it as little as possible.

It's *possible* that your current code would actually work fine if you just changed this:

```
string complete = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(complete);
```

to this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new MemoryStream(data));
```

However, the hex part is pretty ugly. If you really need to represent the binary data as text, I'd strongly recommend using Base64 instead of hex:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(binary);
...
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

... there's no need to convert each byte separately and split the string on hyphens etc.

Comment: Okay , thanks for the input. Could you tell me how to convert the stream to a text string? I tried with a StreamReader, but didnt get it to work. Thanks. Btw; i still get the same problem with the code above :/ As far as the xml encoding tag is concerned, i just forgot to change it. I generate the files so i know that it will always be the same.

Comment: @Johan: Why do you want to do that? Where are you getting the stream? What sort of text do you want it as? For example, to preserve the bytes, you should basically convert it to a byte array and then use `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Comment: The basic idea is to upload the XML file without saving it -> read the stream -> save stream temporary in a hiddenfield as a string format -> send the content of the hiddenfield using jquery ajax to a handler -> handler converts it to XML and generates it as response

Comment: @Johan: Okay, so read the stream into a byte array, convert to text using `Convert.ToBase64String`, transmit to the server, convert back to binary using `Convert.FromBase64String` to get bytes, wrap them in a `MemoryStream`, parse the XML from that.

Comment: It works now, almost. If i do a response.write on complete string, jquery can parse it as xml. But if i try to create a new instance of the XmlDocument, i get `hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character`. Is this because of the \n\r that are in the string?

Comment: @Johan: It's not at all clear to me, but it sounds like *either* it's an invalid file to start with *or* you're still applying an encoding somewhere you shouldn't be.